# Trigger.io doesn't expose the user's agreement to notifications in iOS

Tags: notifications, parse-platform, trigger.io

I am building a trigger.io app (ios+Android) with notifications through parse.com.

Notifications are working, but I am unable to test for whether the user has agreed to notifications before trying to subscribe to a channel with `forge.parse.push.subscribe`. This is generally only a problem on first run of the app.

`forge.parse.installationInfo` will return an `info.id`, even if that user hasn't agreed to notifications, so it can't be used to test for agreement:

`forge.parse.push.subscribe` throws an error if the user hasn't agreed to notifications:

```
{ "message":"Subscribing to Parse channel failed: Error Domain=Parse Code=115
   \\"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 115.)
   \\" UserInfo=0x165ddbc0 {code=115,
   error=There is no device token stored yet.}","type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE"}'
```

I could set a timeout to try subscribing again later in case the user has since accepted notifications, but I'm not happy with having to send multiple REST requests to parse.com to see if the user has agreed to notifications.

`forge.parse.registerForNotifications` just delays the registration process, but doesn't throw an error if the user doesn't agree to notifications.

`Trigger.io` displays a console event when the user accepts:

```
Initializing Parse and subscribing to default channel.
```

Can this also expose an event to forge to be accessed in the js when the user agrees to notifications?

Or should `forge.parse.installationInfo` throw an error if the user doesn't have notifications on?

Comment: does installationInfo return anything else?  Looking at the docs, wondering if you can log that out..

Comment: Fosco: no, installationInfo returns that id only: {"id":"22fdd80c-317b-48b0-b491-***********"}

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a good way, then... You should raise this with Trigger.io support.